# Separability of a Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, separable-spaces

Let $$H=H\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n},\Omega \right)=\left\lbrace v\in L^2\left(\Omega\right):\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_n}\in L^2\left(\Omega\right) \right\rbrace$$
        where $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

$H$ is equipped with the following inner product:
        $$\left(u,v\right)_H=\int_\Omega uvdx+\int_\Omega\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_n}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_n}dx,$$
        and the induced norm is denoted $\left\lVert\cdot\right\rVert_H$ or $\left\lVert\cdot\right\rVert$.

Prove that $H$ is a separable Hilbert space.

I know that for separability I should find a countable and dense subset of $H$, but I have no clue of which is this subset. Thank you for reading.

Comment: You know $L^2$ is separable, so there you have a countable dense subset but in a different inner product. Use it to fit your space.

Comment: For $L^2\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ I do not know a countable dense subset, I just know some sets for $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mimic the standard proof for $W^{1,p}$-separability. Define the map 
$T: H\to L^2(\Omega)^2$ by $Tu = (u, \frac\partial{\partial x_n}u)$.
The clearly $T$  is an isometry. Its range is a subset of a separable space, hence separable. Since $T$ is an isometry also $H$ is separable.